# Send user email through rest services

Tags: users, 8

I made a view, with a contextual filter in the user id. The fields are:

- Name
- uid
- Email.

  [
      {
          "username": "pruthiswebar",
          "id": "8"
      }
  ]

If I am logged, I can see the email, if I go to anonymous user, I can´t. 
There is not a permission for "show user email" or something? How can I configure this?

Comment: The anonymous User does not have an email address. So you are not able to see the email address. Probably I do not understand your question.
What do you want to do? And where in the process?

Comment: i want to show authenticated users.

Comment: To whom? To everybody who is calling the REST-service?

Comment: I think there is no permission to show user data to anonymous user. Normally the user data (except id and username) is only visible to the user itself or user with admin permission.

Comment: @btemperli yes... to everybody

Comment: @btemperli okay, I think it goes beyond the Drupal permissions... If I create other fields for the user, then I can share them without any problem.

Comment: probably it is a setting in the display-options of the user. You find the settings under www.your-domain.com/admin/config/people/accounts/display
But in default, there is no option for hide something for anonymous users.

Comment: Another possibility is to create a hook into the view of the user and add there the user's email. In the hook you can load the whole user and add what you want to the output.

Comment: @btemperli do you have any documentation of that? or how do I look for that? google - hook view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add informations to the view, which are not displaying of whatever reasons - you can hook into the view and "print" the informations manually.

**Step 1** Create a custom module
(https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules)
I'm not sure, but probably you can add the preprocess in the `MYTHEME.theme`-File. Then you do not need your own module for this.

**Step 2** Add the preprocess hook (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/8.5.x)

```
MYMODULE_preprocess_view(&$variables) {
    // Todo: check if the view is the view you want to add the user email.
    $user_id = 1; // Change for other users.
    $user = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load($user_id);
    $variables['users'][$user_id] = $user;
}
```

**Step 3** In the twig-template of the view you can add the userdata (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.5.x)

```
{{ dump(users) }}     {# for the user array. #}
{{ dump(users[1]) }}  {# for the user with the id 1 #}
```